# Which endpoint should be used for getting information about Groups in Office 365?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

There appear to be 2 different endpoints:

1. https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/{resource_path}?{api_version}[odata_query_parameters]
2. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/groups/

And their JSON response formats are also different. Will both continue to be supported? Will the response formats be made consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Please use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups this is the root endpoint for Groups API. For more information visit the documentation at: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group